# HP 2520 poe switch ip configuration trouble

Tags: command-line-interface, switch, hp, ipconfig

I'm configuring an HP 2520 switch by CLI menu interface and i get an error trying to setting this ip config:

default gw: 10.0.0.254
switch ip: 10.0.255.5
subnet-m: 255.255.0.0

The error simply tells: "Unable to set" refering to the default gw.

If i run this command:

```
vlan 1 ip address 10.0.255.5 255.255.0.0
```

I get:

```
10.0.255.5/16: Inconsistent value.
```

Do you know what's wrong with my ip?

Answer (score 1):

It probably hates your use of 255 as your switch's third octet, I know I do, try 254 as a quick test.

Comment: You're right it works... but what's wrong with that 255?

Comment: 255 is broadcast in IP land

Comment: That's weird because with a /16 10.0.255.5 is a perfectly valid host address. 10.0.255.255 would be the broadcast address for that network.